# Powershell Outputting a Log File

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Hello I am new scripting, I am tasked with creating a script that will be deleting a file from specific folders which will be deployed through SCCM onto many computers.

The problem is I want to output the log file saying either:

```
"<ComputerName> File Terminated"
"<ComputerName> File Not terminated"
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
$users = "C:\Users"
$logFile = "C:\TTS\Logs\GoogleTerm.log"
$source = "\AppData\Roaming\Google"
$exclude = "Default"

$input = get-ChildItem -Path $users  

foreach ($folder in $input) {
    if ($exclude -notcontains $folder.Name) {
        Remove-Item -Path ($Users + "\" + $folder.Name + $source) -recurse -force 
    } 
}

echo "Google Terminated on:"$env:computername >> $logfile
```

Comment: Include what you want inside your `if` condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added an [else](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_if) to your `if` to handle both outcomes, and then using [Add-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content) instead of `echo`:

```
foreach ($folder in $input) {
    if ($exclude -notcontains $folder.Name) {
        Remove-Item -Path ($Users + "\" + $folder.Name + $source) -recurse -force 
        Add-Content $logfile "$env:computername File Terminated"
    } 
    else {
        Add-Content $logfile "$env:computername File Not Terminated"
    }
}

Add-Content $logfile "Google Terminated on: $env:computername"
```

Comment: The question is IMO inconsistent as is the outcome of this answer, the `if` excludes the `Default` user on the computer and doesn't say anything about the success of removing folders of other users. With multiple users there will be several lines per computer in the log that can't be distinguished between the users referenced.

Comment: Thank you for your help I was able to successfully implement the script

Answer (score 0):

This was my successfull solution, thank you guys for the assistance!

```
$users =  "C:\Users"

$logFile = "C:\TTS\Logs\GoogleTerm.log"


$exclude = "Default"



$input = get-ChildItem -Path $users 



foreach ($folder in $input) {
if ($exclude -notcontains $folder.Name) {
    if (Test-Path ($Users + "\" + $folder.Name + $source)){
    Remove-Item -Path ($Users + "\" + $folder.Name + $source) -recurse -force

    Add-Content $logFile "Google Terminated on:        $env:computername      UserName:$folder  "
   }
   else{
    Add-Content $logFile "Google Already Terminated on:$env:computername      UserName:$folder  "
   }
}
   else{
        Add-Content $logFile "Not Terminated on:           $env:computername      Username:$folder"
   }
}
```